# How can i preserve wordpress database encoding after using wp-cli search-replace with --export flag?

Tags: search, wp-cli, export, characters

I need to migrate a wordpress database to another server but first i need to change all old url's, stored inside any table, to new ones. To do that, i'm using wp-cli search-replace function with --export flag.

Everything regarding the search-replace method is working good except the encoding of all text of the entire dump. Is there any way to preserve the initial encoded text on the export process ? Like **--default-character-set=utf8mb4** or something ?

Heres an example of the messy encode:

> ATEN├ö├Â┬úÔö£┬║├ö├Â┬úÔö£├│O – Gestores de Acesso dos sistemas Ôö£├ÂÔö£├ºÔö£Ôöñ Mudan├ö├Â┬úÔö¼Ôòæas no Sistema de Gerenciamento e Permiss├ö├Â┬úÔö£├╝es Ôö£├ÂÔö£├ºÔö£Ôöñ (O n├ö├Â┬úÔö£Ôòæo sofrer├ö├Â┬úÔö£┬í essa altera├ö├Â┬úÔö¼Ôòæ├ö├Â┬úÔö£Ôòæo)

Thanks in advance.